# Most reasonable printer for hard plastic ID badges / business cards?

Tags: printer

I'm needing to print, on-demand (or relatively so), a few dozen ID badges and/or hard/transparent "business card" or "gift card"-like cards.  Ideally, they should be full-color and fairly durable as they will be intended to be worn often.

They won't need magnetic strips or chips, just any sort of hard plastic card-shaped thing that can be printed on in relatively high detail; they'll be for visual identification only, with a barcode at most.

Google searches seem to give services that do bulk printing of cards, or expensive enterprise-level card writers that encode magnetic strips or chips in addition to printing.

I just want to be able to print on hard plastic surfaces, ideally spending less than $1000 on the hardware.  I'm sure there's a solution somewhere, but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I say get the [Da Vinci Mini 3D printer](http://us.xyzprinting.com/us_en/Product/da-Vinci-Mini?gclid=Cj0KEQjw1K2_BRC0s6jtgJzB-aMBEiQA-WzDMaw1ftaDHJ7GsbINoP_FOYpRCstQJsRvzppyZmgsnCAaAgM88P8HAQ), use that to print out plastic backings with a lip, and then print out stickers to put on top on a full-color inkjet printer of any description. You're looking at a total cost of well under $500, plus you get a much more versatile bit of kit into the bargain.